# Adjust static value into dynamic (javascript) value possible in Sharepoint allitems.aspx page?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, dynamic

```
<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" IncludeHidden="true" SelectCommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;OrderBy&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;EventDate&quot;/&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Contains&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;lawyer_x0020_1&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Note&quot;&gt;F. Sanches&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Contains&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" id="datasource1" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true"><InsertParameters><asp:Parameter DefaultValue="{ANUMBER}" Name="ListID"></asp:Parameter>
```

SharePoint WSS 3.0

This codeline is just one line of the allitems.aspx of a sharepoint list item (SharePoint created it himself). It only displays items where lawyer 1 = F. Sanches.  Before I start messing around with the .ASPX page I wonder if it possible to change F. Sanches (in the code) into a dynamical variable (from a javascript value or something else that can be used to place the javascript value in there dynamically). If I put any javascript code in the line it will not work.

P.S. Ignore ANUMBER part in code.

Let say to make it simple I have javascript variable like this (now static but with my other code it is dynamic). It would be an achievement if it would place a static javascript variable.

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>javaVAR = "P. Janssen";</script>
```

Eventually I would like to filter with OR operator

If Yes --> how?

If No --> Thank you!

Comment: Without seeing the actual HTML output, it is impossible to determine how this could be adjusted via JavaScript.

Comment: What do you want to see. A screenshot? This line of code and specifically area where P. Janssen is displayed makes the list display only items that are identical to P. Janssen. You can look at it yourself if you have sharepoint wss 3.0. Just adjust the view to filter on a specific field. Open the view in sharepoint designer and you get same result but with different fieldname and value (unless you add the same as I have).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add a filter to a standard list view is to use query string filters - add

```
?FilterField1=Lawyer&FilterValue1=F. Sanches
```

to the url. If you are working with a note field, it probably won't work directly, but you may find it easier to set up a field that does work than to make the server side chages you would need to modify the query directly.

Another approach that might work would be adding filter web parts to the page - I haven't worked with those much myself, but in theory they should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Indeed the query string filter will work to filter. Yet I wonder if it can work with OR operator instead of AND operator.

Comment: Well after some browsing filtering with OR operator is not possible with the query string filter. Also adding filter web parts is not really an option because it can't use a dynmaic variable which is given in a javascript variable. Keep in mind I'm also using Sharepoint WSS 3.0. Ofcourse thanks for the alternatives, but I still wonder about my question. Filtering a calendar view dynamically seems also not to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JavaScript will work since JavaScript is client side and [SPDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spdatasource.aspx) is server side.

However, you should be able to use a control via [ControlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter.aspx). There are good examples [here](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2008/07/spdatasource-every-developer-friend.html) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/03/05/asp-net-controls-filter-the-data-view.aspx). Once the parameters are working, OR operators will definitely be supported within the CAML of the [SelectCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spdatasource.selectcommand.aspx).